# Liquibase ignores @NotNull

Tags: hibernate, liquibase

I have @NotNull annotation on some fields. However when I try to generate a diffChangelog, it drops all the not null constraints

Sample Class :

```
public class User {

    @NotNull
    private String email;
}
```

The diffChangeSet :

```
<changeSet author="author (generated)" id="1437485184491-4">
    <dropNotNullConstraint columnDataType="varchar(255)" columnName="email" tableName="user"/>
</changeSet>
```

The only solution seems to be adding an extra annotation @Column(nullable = false) on every field. Can i do anything so that I do not have to add an extra annotation on every field.

Comment: Doesn't liquibase rely on information from the database? If so, wouldn't this actually more be a Hibernate/DDL script issue?

Comment: Are you using the [liquibase hibernate extension](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki) to generate your diff? If so what version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: Yes. I am using liquibase-hibernate4.version = 3.5

Comment: Hello @KechitGoyal, have you found a solution except `nullable=false`? `nullable=false` actually do not work for me.

Comment: For me also    changing @Column(name = "foo", nullable = true) did n't work. any suggestion?

Comment: This issue seems still to persist, I am using liquibase 3.6.3. It seems @NotNull are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

if anyone still has problem with this I recently found out that it has been fixed in [liquibase-hibernate5-3.7](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/releases/tag/liquibase-hibernate5-3.7)

Answer (score 0):

Currently it works for me when I set addtional:

```
@Column(nullable = false)
```

Somehow @NotNull is not working well with that `org.liquibase.ext.liquibase-hibernate5`